# is there a way to cancel a key such that I can still read from it later with java nio

Tags: java, netty, nio, mina

We would like get tcp flow control as a primary component of a new java nio library.  It would work like this...

1. library fires data to Listener.incomingData(DataChunk dataChunk);
2. library will not fire any more data EVEN if there is any until dataChunk.processed() is called.
3. Typically, you may call processed() method on the first few dataChunks but on the last one of some message, you write to some remote socket and give it a callback handler.
4. once the write callback is called, you then invoke the last dataChunk.processed() to relieve the tcp flow control again

BIG NOTE: Step 2 is where tcp flow control automatically kicks in IF you do not read from the nic buffer.  This is all automatic (and we tested it with java nio).  The issue though is how do we put the key in a state that the poller STOPS releasing and waits for data on all OTHER sockets except this one.  I don't mind if it releases when it has new data as we would see that the last dataChunk has not been processed and ignore it, but we don't want the poller thread cycling 100% cpu.  Is there a way to achieve this so we can acheive automatic throttling for any server using this potential open source nio framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cancel it and re-register the channel later, or just de-register it for `OP_READ,` by changing its `interestOps()`, and change them back when you are ready to read from it again.

Answer (score 1):

No, Selectors will look at their internal state not events from the system, so while the key
is set to sense readable data it will always return while data is in the buffer waiting to
be read.

There are three options you have

read the data from the buffer and store locally while you wait from the previous chunk to
process.

unregister the key from the selector and reregister when the chunk has been processed.

set the key to not sense readble and reset when the chunk has been processed.

I think this is what you want, to toggle reading interest

```
selectionKey.interestOps(selectionKey.interestOps() ^ SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

Comment: I don't know what 'No, Selectors will look at their internal state not events from the system' is supposed to mean, especially when the rest of your answer says 'yes'. It is the whole purpose of Selectors to 'look at events from the system'.